# Como usar de forma dinamica propiedades javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando cambiar el estado de algunas propiedades de forma dinámica.

Por ejemplo:

```
var o = document.getElementById(valor);
o.style.DISPLAY = none;
```

Quiero pasar DISPLAY como una variable, igual que la `var o`

¿Como se puede hacer?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: No se entiende. Te recomiendo agregar un ejemplo de lo que quieres hacer